# How to create a regex which will include numbers, letter or one dot

Tags: javascript, regex

I created a regex like this: `const pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;`

which works fine for numbers and letters but I want to modify it a little bit so it can include only one dot but that to be optional.

Comment: Can the dot bet at the start or at the end, and should you also be able to match an empty string?

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of tutorials on regex, including [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) which also makes it easy to test and inspect your regexes.

The main thing you have to look out for is that `.` outside a range is a special "keyword" meaning "match every non-newline character". You need to escape it by adding `\` in front of it, e.g. `\.`.

You can also use `\d` which will match any digit, instead of having to use `0-9` inside a range.

Since you only expect one optional dot, you can simply duplicate your range and add a dot inbetween: `/^[a-zA-Z\d]*\.?[a-zA-Z\d]*$/`

Comment: Thanks Kevin this was really helpful

Comment: @arberhaxhimusa In that case, don't forget to mark this answer as the solution

Comment: @Kevin Schoofs won't let me, but I hope that the comment will help other users that visit.